# How to use make a cell segue after doing a UISearch and filtering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been creating and app with a TableView and a UISearch bar.  The cells are selectable but the problem is I have cells preforming segues if they are selected.

Code for this:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("First", sender: tableView)
    }
```

When the user completes a filted search those cells now have different text in it.  So the thing they tap is then presents the wrong view.  Is their a way to make the my if statement above be if the Row is equal to a specific Sting in my array.

My array: 
`var menu = ["first", "Second", "Third","Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"]`

When the user doesn't do a search they cell and the text match but once the user does a search the cells stay where they are same with the segue but the text that the cell has is different.

MAIN PROBLEM: The cells text is not equal to the right view that should be presented after the search and filter.  They are just segueing no matter what the cell text is.

If someone could provide me with new code or adjust the existing code that would be great.
Ask me with any questions or if you need and clarification. All of my code is in swift. Thanks for the help!

New code:

```
  func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = menu.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound

        let menu = ["First", "Second", "Third","Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"]
        // when a search is done you check if your array contains the search result
        if menu.contains(searchBar.text!) {
            // you change the search to lowercase
            // so keep all your segue identifiers with lowercase strings
            let identifier = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
            // perform the segue
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: tableView)




        }
```

Comment: Do you want to segue to some of the menu data? first, second, third etc?

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry.  I want the segues and the label of to stay together so when the user for example searches Third they can tap on it with out it segueing to the view for the first or the first cell on the table.  The text of the cell changes based on the users search so they think oh is the view for third but really it is the view for first because the first cell segues to the the view controller for first.  If this makes any sense.

Comment: Do you want labels that the user can press on and then segue to different viewControllers?

Comment: Yes but I want the view to correspond with the text after the search has been done.

Comment: Feel free to ask me more questions.

Comment: Why would you need a search? Isn´t it better to have a dropdown list where the user can choose a value and then navigate to that viewController?

Comment: I have am going to have a lot of things on that table view eventually so it would be more efficient to do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your searchBar and when you make the search you will have the keyword from the search, then you could do like this:

```
// Your array
let menu = ["first", "Second", "Third","Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"]
// when a search is done you check if your array contains the search result
if menu.contains(searchBar.text) {
      // you change the search to lowercase
      // so keep all your segue identifiers with lowercase strings
      let identifier = searchBar.text.lowercaseString
      // perform the segue
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: tableView)
}
```

**Update**
If you want to `segue` on a row click do the following

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let identifier = menu[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: tableView)
```

**Update 2**

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let menu = ["first" , "Second", "Third","Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"]
        // when a search is done you check if your array contains the search result
        // if yes
        if menu.contains(searchText.text!) {
            // you change the saerchText to lowercase
            // so keep all your segue identifiers with lowercase strings
            let identifier = searchbar.text!.lowercaseString
            // perform the segue
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: tableView)
        }
    })
```

**Final solution that solved OP´s question**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let menu = ["first", "second", "third","fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]
    // when a search is done you check if your array contains the search result

    let identifier = cell?.textLabel?.text!.lowercaseString

    if menu.contains(identifier!) {
        // you change the search to lowercase
        // so keep all your segue identifiers with lowercase strings
        // perform the segue
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier!, sender: tableView)  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user does a search, is that the results are sorted in a new array or the data are sorted in the initial array?

If the data is sort in a different array you can simply add a boolean flag that indicate when the table view need to use the filtered array. So in your

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     
}
```

you could have

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (userHasSearch){
        //  Something with the filtered array of data
    } else {
        //  Something with the initial array
    }
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: No they are not sorted again